# Change argv strings in function in C with pointers

Tags: arrays, c, char, arguments, c-strings

Is it possible to change argv strings you give program at the startup, in a function? Not using return? I managed to do it with integer(change its value while passing pointer), but Im struggling with strings. What would the syntax look like? I'm really confused about the whole pointers thing :D.

```
void changestrings(char*strings[]){
    char*newstrings[5] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
    *strings = newstrings;    
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    changestrings(&argv);
    (void)argc;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in C are denoted with `char *`. What this means is that the string itself is stored contiguously, but the variable's actual value is an address in memory, not the string. That address points to the first character in the string.

`char *argv[]` denotes an array of these pointers. This array is stored the same way; `argv`'s "value" is just a memory address pointing to the first element in the array.

When you take the address of that array, you're taking the address in memory of the variable itself, not of its contents. You can then pass this address to a function to modify that variable, which is what you're doing here.

Here's the fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void changestrings(char **strings[]) { // 1
    char *newstrings[5] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    *strings = newstrings;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    changestrings(&argv);
    // (void)argc // 2
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

(I've included a `printf` to help demonstrate that the change worked.)

At `// 1`, your original function had an argument of type `char *[]`. This is incorrect, as you're passing an *address* to a `char *[]` when you use `&` on `argv`. Therefore, this should be `char **[]` (or `char ***`).

At `// 2`, I'm not sure what you're attempting, but if you want to change the value of `argc`, you can simply assign to it in `main` or take its address and modify it in another function.

---

Do note that you can also simply assign to `argv` if you define a new `char *[]` in `main`. If you want to change individual strings, that becomes slightly trickier as you need to keep track of how many are in the array, but that code would look something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void change_first_string(char *strings[], int strings_length) {
    if (strings_length < 2) return;
    strings[0] = "foo";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    change_first_string(argv, argc);
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that (void)argc is so that i dont get errors for unused variable. running with -wall -werror -wextra